# Is winston logger uses main thread of node js

Tags: node.js, winston

I am using lots of logger.info in my function
and I think, it is consuming much time,

So, can you please tell me, Does it uses the main thread of node js?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's the default behavior. JavaScript is single-threaded. If you don't start a new thread or process, it runs into the same thread.

Comment: You mean, javascript will wait for logger to log the statement after that next line will execute and this process will not go asynchronous

Comment: Yes, there is no automatic asynchronous logging in Winston. Winston doesn't contain code to create threads or processes.